# Most efficient way to select a given layer programmatically in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

this a question about code efficiency, not asking how to loop through layers. I'm getting the 'this question appears subjective...' warning but there must be a tried and tested method by someone more adept at PyQGIS programming than me! I don't intend to start a discussion, just hopefully someone more experienced can objectively say "do it like this instead" or "that's the best/only way".

I'm only just starting to use QGIS and PyQGIS to develop...stuff. Most of the operations I will be doing, and indeed all of them up until this point, will be using some layer that's in the map registry. So every function I have so far starts like this:

```
def some_function(layer, parameter, another_parameter):
    for lyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if lyr.name() == layer:
        # and then whatever it is I need to do or get from this layer
```

Is this the most efficient way of going about this, or is there another way of proceeding without looping through all layers and then having the `if` statement to ID the layer. Clearly the more layers you have open, the more computationally expensive this would be, perhaps there is a way of selecting the layer by its name directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select layers by name directly with:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("layer_name")
```

It returns a list of all layers that name contains "layer_name".

Comment: `sed -i s/contains/equals/'`